# How can I change a value in consul K/V Store from Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, consul

I use Consul's Key/Value Store as a PropertySource in a Spring Boot 2 app. (org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul-config)

I can read the properties from the K/V Store with @ConfigurationProperties and even update them with @RefreshScope when I change the value via the Consul web interface.

But I do have some dynamic properties which can change in the application.
How do I propagate these changes to Consul, so that the values are actually changed.
I tried to use the Setter for the property but that did not change the value in Consul.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this code to set KV values. 
Create private variable.

```
@Autowired
private ConsulClient consulClient;
```

change KVs using setKVValue() method.

```
consulClient.setKVValue("key", "value")
```